# Control topbar with react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Im new at react native and I'm trying to do a simple aplication.

I just put a text and this is result in Nexus 5:

[image: The result]

I understood that putting SaveAreaView this would be fixed but it dosen't.

```
 return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
       <Text style={styles.principalTitle}>Just a text</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
 );
```

How I can control the top bar for the text apears in a visible zone? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> The purpose of SafeAreaView is to render content within the safe area
>   boundaries of a device. It is currently only applicable to iOS devices
>   with iOS version 11 or later. - [SafeAreaView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview)

In your case the SafeAreaView has no effect, but you can pass a `marginTop` to the view or directly to your text. E.g. :

```
 return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 20 }}>
       <Text style={styles.principalTitle}>Just a text</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
 );
```

Comment: Yes... but no way to control the height of topbar? Maybe some mobiles have diferent heights (I don't know).

Comment: @JordiCastillo I'm not aware of such an option.

Comment: Look at my answer!

Comment: Mee too :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Following Tim reference answer I improved him code.

With React Native you can control status bar height:

```
import {...  , StatusBar} from 'react-native';

return (
   <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight }}>
      <Text style={styles.principalTitle}>Just a text</Text>
   </SafeAreaView>
);
```

I prefered padding for conserve Background.

Thank you!